# Instagram Api - how to find a valid max_id & min_id

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

hi i'm using instagram api with javascript.  i want to get a tag 5 posts and the api return this error:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "pagination": {
        "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
    },
    "data": [ ]}
```

i'm using this url to get posts:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=xxx&count=5
```

what is max_id and min_id?? how i can find a valid max_id or min_id